# Can't use negative right margin on table element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use table-cell elements in a grid system that utilizes negative margins on rows to eliminate the left and right gutters on nested grid elements.  This works fine on floated and inline-block elements, but elements with `display: table`, while respecting the negative left margin, ignore the negative right margin:

[image: Table with negative right margin]

Strange, eh? A simple demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/57FAN/1/

All browsers seem to have implemented this the same way, unfortunately.  Any ideas?

P.S.  Let's postpone the debate over table-* elements for layout until flex box is standardized.

Comment: There is no reason to postpone the debate over tables for layout just like there is no reason to use tables for layout.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks the OP isn't using tables, he is using the table display properties.  The rule is to not use the table tag for layout because it is designed for expressing tabular data, not that you can't make non-table elements look like a table.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't catch that. Of course use of the display: table; property is totally legit (not sarcasm). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table doesn't ignore the negative margin, but is only 100% in width and shifted 5px to the left. You would need a "100% + 2*5px" to fill the grey area entirely.

The row doesn't have a width, thus uses the entire width available.

If you would use

```
.row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

you would see that the widths are equal

Comment: Ah, you're correct.  I didn't consider that width:auto on a block level element isn't always the same as width:100%.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have more `margin` and `padding` property's. so its look like that. Here I corrected some codes.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/57FAN/8/)

Comment: Thanks Selva, but the margins and padding are part of a grid system and can't be removed.